# SQL output based on a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following two table scenario, how would I go about outputting the commission percentage based on the date range:

Commission Percentages

```
 | User ID  | Start Date | End Date    | Percentage
 | -------- | ---------- | ----------- | ----------
 | 1        | 11/11/2014 | 11/30/2014  | 10%
 | 1        | 11/30/2014 |   NULL      | 20%
 | 2        | 10/10/2014 |   NULL      | 15%
```

Sales

```
 | User ID  | Sale Date  | 
 | -------- | ---------- | 
 | 1        | 11/24/2014 | 
 | 1        | 12/1/2014  | 
 | 2        | 12/30/2014 |
```

I would like to end up with a join between the two like so (a null value in the end date field represents present - and the dates will also include a time stamp):

```
 | User ID  | Sales Date | Start Date | End Date    | Percentage
 | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------  | ----------
 | 1        | 11/24/2014 | 11/11/2014 | 11/30/2014  | 10%
 | 1        | 12/1/2014  | 11/30/2014 |   NULL      | 20%
 | 2        | 12/30/2014 | 10/10/2014 |   NULL      | 15%
```

I am using SQL Server 2012

Thanks

Comment: can you paste output you expect?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you, however you need to figure your date logic (i.e. whether it should be greater than, or greater than/equal to) depending on how your system works:

```
select S.UserID, S.SalesDate, C.StartDate, C.EndDate, C.Percentage
from Sales AS S
inner join Commission AS C
 on C.UserID = S.UserID
 AND S.SalesDate > C.StartDate
 AND S.SalesDate <= coalesce(C.EndDate, S.SalesDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the end date is the first date the percentage does not apply based on the data.  User ID 1 has a vector overlap.

```
SELECT s.User_ID,
    s.Sales_Date,
    cp.Start_Date,
    cp.End_Date,
    cp.Pecrcentage
FROM Commission_Percentages cp
INNER JOIN Sales s
    ON  s.User_ID = cp.User_ID
    AND s.Sale_Date >= cp.Start_Date
    AND (s.Sale_Date < cp.End_Date OR cp.End_Date IS NULL)
```